# how to exchange transparent background image

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have a span with a transparent background image:

`<span style="background: url(icon1.png) no-repeat left center;"></span>`

On hover I want the background image to change, for which I created a hover effect:

```
.style1:hover {
  background: url(icon2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

It works in a way that the new image is layered on top, but given that it's transparent, you can still see the old image underneath.

```css
.style1:hover {
  background: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/3777-200.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="style1">
    <span style=" background: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66460-200.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:25px 25px;padding-left: 50px;"></span>
  </div>
```

Is there any easy fix for this?

Many thanks

David

Comment: you mean you see both icon1 and icon2 on hover ? can you create a snippet and show us this behavior

Comment: That is just not possible, I can bet you can't see the image you want on hover; it is impossible to change the background if you have it inline style unless you use **!important**

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's right, I see both at the same time on hover because icon2 is transparent and doesnt exchange icon1 it's just on top!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the span add use `!important` to override the inline style.

```css
.style1:hover span {
  background-image: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/3777-200.png)!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="style1">
  <span style=" background: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/66460-200.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:25px 25px;padding-left: 50px;"></span>
</div>
```